Deploying a python Function App where the source is in a subdirectory
I've got a mono-repo with a python project that I'm deploying to Azure. There's an API being deployed as a container and I'm trying to add a function app.
My python code is structured in a few folders underneath a /backend folder, like
./backend
./backend/domain/ - contains domain logic .py files
./backend/entrypoints/api - contains Flask app files
./backend/entrypoints/my-func - contains my new function app
./backend/... - various other folder hierarchies that are imported.

I have a venv set up and a requirements.txt in the root of the project.
The function app imports domain and other modules. All folders have an __init__.py to mark them as modules.
I'm struggling to run the project. If I func start in the ./backend/entrypoints/my-func directory I get a ModuleNotFoundError:
Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'. Cannot find module. Please check the requirements.txt file for the missing module. 

My flask app can load dotenv just fine and it's in the requirements.txt and installed.
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
... 
Requirement already satisfied: python-dotenv~=1.0.1 in /home/greg/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/envs/fish12-2/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 27)) (1.0.1)
...

Is this possible?

By installing dotenv as it? pip install dotenv ?

@JulienSorin sorry, I don't follow. dotenv is already installed.

Set PYTHONPATH to ensure Python locates the directories that contain the modules and also allows you to control which directories can be included in the module search path.
Eg: set PYTHONPATH=../../../
I have followed below steps to use the modules in the sub-directory of the project.
Project Structure:
Monorepo
|
|---requirements.txt
\---env
|
+---backend
|   \---entrypoint
|       +---api
|       |       app.py
|       |
|       \---my-func
|           |   .gitignore
|           |   function_app.py
|           |   host.json
|           |   local.settings.json
|           |
|           +---.vscode
|           |       extensions.json
|           |
|           \---__pycache__
|                   function_app.cpython-311.pyc

requirements.txt
azure-functions
flask
python-dotenv

Create and activate virtual environment in the root directory:
py -m venv env
.\env\Scripts\activate

Install the packages in the virtual environment:
pip install -r requirements.txt


Navigate to the function folder and run the command:
(env) C:\Users\uname\monorepo\backend\entrypoint\my-func>set PYTHONPATH=../../../

Able to run the function with dotenv module:
code snippet:
import azure.functions as func
import datetime
import json
import logging
from dotenv import load_dotenv

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.route(route="http_trigger", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

Response:
(env) C:\Users\uname\monorepo\backend\entrypoint\my-func>func start
Found Python version 3.11.9 (py).

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5907 Commit hash: N/A +807e89766a92b1XXX8777ab209 (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.834.3.22875

[2024-08-30T07:39:25.263Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        http_trigger:  http://localhost:7071/api/http_trigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-08-30T07:39:30.124Z] Executing 'Functions.http_trigger' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=bc1ffc1c-089b-47f4-XX3108)
[2024-08-30T07:39:30.228Z] Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-08-30T07:39:30.362Z] Executed 'Functions.http_trigger' (Succeeded, Id=bc1ffc1c-089b-47f4-992XXX08, Duration=252ms)
[2024-08-30T07:39:30.384Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.



can you take a look at this follow up quesiton please.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78931861/how-to-deploy-a-python-azure-function-app-from-a-mono-repo
