How to deploy a Python Azure Function app from a mono-repo?
Following on from this question, I've got a mono-repo containing a Flask API and the first of what will be several Azure Function apps. I'm trying to deploy the app to Azure from an Azure DevOps pipeline.
How do I deploy the app and tell azure where the entry point is?
My python code is structured in a few folders underneath a /backend folder, like
./backend
./backend/domain/             - contains domain logic .py files
./backend/entrypoints/api     - contains Flask app files
./backend/entrypoints/my-func - contains my new function app
./backend/...                 - various other folder hierarchies that are imported.

I've got an AzureFunctionApp@2 task and it's pushing a zip of the project up to a Storage Account but I can't see any Functions registered in the Azure Portal.

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: Package Function Apps
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
        archiveType: 'zip'
        archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/nightly-import-$(Build.BuildId).zip'
        verbose: true

    - task: AzureFunctionApp@2
      displayName: Deploy Nightly Importer
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: ${{parameters.azureServiceConnection}}
        appType: functionAppLinux
        appName: nightly-import-${{parameters.environmentMoniker}}-uks-01
        package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/FuncAppsPackage/nightly-import-$(Build.BuildId).zip'
        deploymentMethod: auto
        verbose: true


How do you publish a function app from within a mono-repo in such a way that all dependencies are deployed, including pip packages from the venv and 1st party python modules from outside the function app folder (my backend/domain and other modules)?

Check if this article helps.

@PravallikaKV I'm not sure it does. I can see they're zipping a sub-package but where are they saying "include all the other module and pip packages" (obviously they're using JS so they don't have pip packages).

To deploy the Mono repo to Azure function app, configure rootFolderOrFile to the function directory in the workflow.
YAML pipeline:
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/backend/entrypoints/my-func/*'  # Path to your Function App code
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: 'zip'
        archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- task: AzureFunctionApp@1
      displayName: 'Azure Functions App Deploy'
      inputs:
           azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
           appType: 'functionAppLinux'
           appName: '$(functionAppName)'
           package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'

I have deployed  the same using GitHub actions:
Workfow:
name: Build and deploy Python project to Azure Function App - appname

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: 'backend/entrypoint/my-func'
  PYTHON_VERSION: '3.11'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v5
        with:
          python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          pip install -r requirements.txt
      # Optional: Add step to run tests here

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: |
          mkdir -p package
          cp -r ${AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH}/* package/
          cp requirements.txt package/
          cd package
          zip -r ../release.zip .
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: release.zip

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-function.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: python-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip -d deployment

      - name: List files in deployment directory
        run: ls -R deployment

      - name: Deploy to Azure Functions
        uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
        id: deploy-to-function
        with:
          app-name: 'appname'
          package: 'deployment'
          scm-do-build-during-deployment: true
          enable-oryx-build: true
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_C8CFCXXXXDCC }}

Deployed to Azure:

Portal:


Thanks for the response @pravallikakv, but the function app references modules outside of it's root folder, e.g. in the /backend/domain folder, so they need to be bundled too, along with any pip dependencies.

As I have shown in the GitHub workflow, it copies therequirements.txt folder(from root directory) too where I have function modules.

@GregB, Are you able to deploy? If not, please share your repository link(excluding sensitive information), I'll try to deploy from my end.
